# H2 - DATEADD for complete day

Tags: sql, date, h2

this query will retrieve all records during last 7 days.

```
SELECT * FROM STATISTICS WHERE TIMESTAMP > DATEADD('DAY',-7, NOW())
```

How can I change the query to include the records from midnight 7 days ago?

ex.

```
SELECT DATEADD('DAY',-7, NOW())
```

Gives:  **2013-09-25 13:46:54.372**

But I would like to have: **2013-09-25 00:00:00.000**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is a solution.

Using **CURRENT_DATE** instead of **NOW()** does the trick!

ex:

```
SELECT * FROM STATISTICS WHERE TIMESTAMP > DATEADD('DAY',-7, CURRENT_DATE)
```

http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd

Comment: I used this: DATEADD('DAY',-10, CURRENT_DATE()

Answer (score -1):

in SQL Server you can do this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Maybe you can adjust this to work in H2 as well.